# Where is the ERC 20 token code?

Tags: erc-20

I've read about and understand the idea behind the ERC20 Token Standard, but is there an official contract people can download and use? Or is it an official list of functions a smart contract should include in order to be up to standard?

Anyone know where I can find a polished and ready to go version of ERC20? 
I first read about it here: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
And I also looked at this: https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard

Or am I missing something super obvious?

Comment: Check out [OpenZeppelin's implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/StandardToken.sol) of a standard ERC20 token for an example that follows best security practices.

Comment: Yes, it is an agreed upon list of functions + events a smart contract must include to meet the standard.  See the answer by Eth to this question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16714/what-are-the-key-criteria-for-meeting-the-erc20-token-standard.  In the comments, we asked if there was an official list somewhere.  So far, it seems like the Ethereum wiki and the github threads are the only 2 places that list these 6 functions + 2 events that make up the ERC20 standard, and the specific words in which they need to be written. For instance: "TotalSupply" not "TotalCoinSupply"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ERC20 standard defines an interface, which is the name of the functions as well as their signature. Signature means a list of their arguments. It also defines what these functions should do. But it does not define **how** you implement it and thus it does not include any code.

For some suggested implementations, have a look at this GitHub repo:
https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens

Comment: If that's your real name, you have the coolest name ever.

Comment: "It also defines what these functions should do."  < This feels confusing to me,  I think what Thorkil meant to say here is that "It also defines what each function returns".   So basically it says, if you want to call yourself an ERC-20 you have to offer these functions that return these types of things.  Other than that, do what you want!

Comment: Also possibly helpful: [The ERC20 Token Standard Interface](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard#The_ERC20_Token_Standard_Interface) according to Wikipedia.